# Get invoices from Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get list of invoices for specific customer from Stripe using PHP.

Following is the code I'm using.

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');
 $response = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array('customer' => 'CUSTOMER_TOKEN'));
```

But this returns empty array.

Instead, CURL command returns result

```
 curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices?customer=CUSTOMER_TOKEN  -u STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
```

Any idea?

I'm using `Stripe PHP library` available from Github.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

Comment: you either pasted the wrong customer id in the code or the wrong secret key if it works with curl and not PHP.

Comment: @koopajah, If I put wrong API secret Key or invalid customer id, I get exception, not empty response.

Comment: Is the array really empty or are you getting a PHP error here? If it's empty you'd need to contact support and give them the customer id you're trying to retrieve so that they can help you. Otherwise it must mean that something is wrong in your PHP script and seeing the full script (without the keys) would help

Answer (score 2):

```
$response = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array('customer' => 'cus_id'));
```

You need to add customer id for specific customer.